# Using dxautocomplete dynamically

Tags: jquery, ajax, devextreme

Friends

I created dxautocomplete in devextreme mobile dxlist. But only the first line is formed. I want each line and I want to get different data on each line. To be dynamic. I know that the same code always comes up in the code below, but how to change it and how to display it on each line?

**Html code**

```
   <div data-bind="dxList:{dataSource: [{ key: 1, title: 'Number' },
   { key:2,title: 'Item2' }]}">
   <div data-options="dxTemplate : { name: 'item' } ">
   <div data-bind="text: title"></div>
   <div id="a"></div>                    
   </div>
   </div>
```

**Js code**

```
   $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url:MYURL,
    success: function (msg, result, status, xhr) {
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(msg);
    $("#a").dxAutocomplete({
    dataSource: obj,
    displayExpr: 'Name'// ı want to  this dynamic 
    });} });
```

[image: OUTPUT]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your sample you mix up two approaches KnockoutJS and jQuery. Moreover, you are using `id="a"` for an each list item. But `id` should be unique.

So, in your case I suggest you are moving autocomplete initialization to the item template:

```
<div data-bind="dxList:{dataSource: [/*...*/]}">
<div data-options="dxTemplate : { name: 'item' } ">
    <div data-bind="text: title"></div>
    <div data-bind="dxAutocomplete: $root.getAutocompleteOptions.call($data)"></div>
</div>
```

There is the `$root.getAutocompleteOptions` function that calculates option for each autocomplete. Pay attention, you should change the context for this function:

```
$root.getAutocompleteOptions.call($data)
```

It allows you to define what list item is currently rendering:

```
getAutocompleteOptions: function() {
    var currentListItem = this;
    if(currentListItem.key === 1) { /*...*/ }
}
```

I've created a demo here - https://jsfiddle.net/aj6rrjza/

Comment: Thank you . Even with another question, how many data future is uncertain with this dxlist. How to solve a situation like Key == 2. Maybe there will be three data maybe five

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question)) Anyway you have the `getAutocompleteOptions` function that calculates the autocomplete options depend on list item. So, it's up to you how to decide what options will be passed to autocomplete.

Comment: Okey, I understand. I'll try again.

Comment: hi @sergey can you help me pls for  this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41776687/how-can-i-make-text-dynamic-in-dxlist

Comment: please excuse me. But I need help @sergey. If you do not want to help, I understand you. :)

Comment: How can I help you @Girl_engineer?

Comment: thank you..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41907520/how-to-write-data-in-textbox