# How can I make Text dynamic in dxlist

Tags: jquery, ajax, devextreme

I am using devextreme dxlist with ajax. I want to use dxlist text dynamically. So text should not be fixed constantly. I can make dynamic using the variable text with ajax, but how to use the js variable in html. I have codes below. How can I make Text dynamic?

**Html code**

```
 <div  data-bind="dxList: { dataSource: dataSource,pullRefreshEnabled:true}">
 <div  data-options="dxTemplate : { name: 'item' } ">
 <div  data-bind="**text: UserName"**></div></div></div>//This text is dynamic
```

Comment: What do you mean 'dynamic text'? Do you want to update the `UserName` via JavaScript? If so, [ko.observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html) will be helpful.

Comment: @Sergey The username in this is the value that is also in the json data. But this text remains constant. For example, I want to write a text variable with ajax and write text .. The text will change continuously. But I do not understand how to do that.

Comment: In short, that's what I want to do. I have a listbox that has a list of textboxes. I want the list of values ​​to be written when writing a value to a textbox. For example, if the user name is the user name. If it is age, develop a list of ages.

Comment: And by typing in a selection from this inbox, write to the textbox. So this list should change according to what is always written to the textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you need to wrap each dataSource item with `ko.observable();`. You can use the [dataSource.map](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/16_2/ApiReference/Data_Layer/DataSource/Configuration/#map) option to do this:

```
dataSource: {
    store: [/* your data */],
    map: function(item, index) {
        return {
            name: ko.observable(item.name),
            age: ko.observable(item.age)
        };
    }
}
```

Next, you can use these observable values as textbox values:

```
<div data-options="dxTemplate : { name: 'name-template' } ">
    <div data-bind="dxTextBox: { value: name }"></div>
</div>
```

In [this sample](https://jsfiddle.net/evbs0efx/5/) I use two arrays(`names` and `ages`) to store the data that is connected with the list.

Also I use two templates 'name-template' and 'age-template' to show the particular data field in the list.

Hope this information helps you.

Comment: Thank you . It was different than what I wanted to do.I did what I wanted, but there is something I do wrong. I got a different mistake. Can I share with you?

Comment: Sure, you can))

Comment: Thanks. I tried to do it using dxlist "data-bind = text: dynamic variable" is the same as the field name in the database. When you need to bring the data. it writes the variable name. For example, Text: Name,  it writes Name as lines, However, jack, tom should write names like.

Comment: Could you provide the fiddle that demonstrates your issue?

Comment: Would you send me a screen shot? I can not make an example because I work with ajax.

Comment: You can use $.ajax inside jsfiddle. Look at this http://jsfiddle.net/sergfry/2faddorc/2/  Unfortunately, I can't understand your requirements without a real sample.

Comment: thank you. I used your example. The sample was useful to me.